# Function size limit 32K

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm having a problem with the BigQuery function text size limitation “Definition body too long: 57399; maximum allowed: 32768 bytes." Does this limit depend on the tariff or is it a physical limit? There is no such restriction on a procedure, view or a normal request.

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `TEST.Hello_Friends`()
AS (
ARRAY (
WITH Hello AS ( SELECT 2 AS aText )
...
SELECT AS STRUCT *
FROM ( SELECT 1 AS aBODY )
)
)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, inline code blobs have a limit of 32 KB. If you are using in-line code blob >32kb then the recommendation is to use EXTERNAL_QUERY function with blob on cloud storage.

Quotas for UDFs in BQ. Link Below
[UDF Quota](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#udf_limits)

Comment: Well, I found in documentation, that function has limit 32K, but I found, that for table function such limit is not declared.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#table_functions

In fact, table function is replacement for view. View has limit 256K

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#view_limits

Comment: As I understand TVF is not the same as UDF. UDF is much more universal and complicate thing, because allow to use another language, as example JavaScript